# Adapt SF Symbols to iOS version

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, sf-symbols

I'm currently developing an iOS app that has iOS 13 set as deployment target. I'm using some SF symbols throughout the app. Now, since iOS 14 and a new version of XCode have been available, I've been getting a warning about one of my symbols being deprecated (`paragraphsign` should be used instead of `paragraph`), however, when I change the image to `paragraphsign` in Interface Builder, I'm getting an error saying that this symbol is only available in iOS 14...

Now, my current solution is to ignore the warning and instead use

```
if #available(iOS 14, *)
{
    ...
}
```

in my code to replace all deprecated images with their new versions.

My question is: Is there a way to do this in Interface Builder directly to avoid the warning? Something like "use this in iOS 14 and that in prior versions"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option, if you don't want to just ignore the warning...

Using the SF Symbols app, select the "paragraphsign" and:

```
File -> Export Custom Symbol Template
```

Save it as `paragraphsign.svg` and then drag it into your asset catalog. ***That*** image will be used when running on iOS 13... the actual `paragraphsign` SF Symbol will be used when running on iOS 14.

No code needed.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting from SF Symbols and then using this svg in asset catalog is working only if you use a name for Symbol image without dots ("."). For example: Symbol image name "speaker.wave.1.fill" won't work. Warning will disappear, but symbol will not show on WatchOS 6. When I renamed same Symbol Image to "Speaker1fill" and use this image instead of system image, it worked for all WatchOS versions.

Comment: This answer by itself makes no sense.  If you wish to expand on another answer please use add comment. Thanks.